# Keep content when pressing back

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a view with two dropdown, each option navigate to different page (not ajax). I'm using laravel

```
<select onChange="window.location.href = this.value" id="selection" name="type" title="Document selection">
     <option value="/document/gup-accepted">-Choose Document Type-</option>
     <option selected value="/document/gup-accepted/fac">Faculty/option>
     <option value="/document/gup-accepted/univ">University</option>
```

here's my one of my controller (each other similar)

```
public function  getAcceptedGUPFaculty()
{

    $user = Auth::user();
    $roles = $user->showRoleSlug();
    $fac = new Document();

    $fac = $fac->getAcceptedFacultyGUP($roles)->paginate(5);

    if (request()->ajax()) {

        return response()->json(view('layouts.gup-fac', array('fac' => $fac))->render());
    }

    return view('accepted-gup-faculty',compact('fac'));
}
```

each page has pagination with ajax request, ajax pagination works perfectly and when i press previous and next still works fine.
but when i go to option 1 and move to option 2. page only shows my partial blade templates and it doesnt show full page contents.

here's my javascript:

```
 <script>

    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (isNaN(page) || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            }else{
                getData(page);
            }
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){


    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'fac',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
        })

        .done(function(data)
        {
            $("#results").empty().html(data);
        })
        .fail(function()
        {
            alert('No response from server');
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(event)
        {
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
            event.preventDefault();
            page = $(this).attr('href').split('fac?page=')[1];
            getData(page);
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            window.history.pushState("","", url);
        });
    });

    function getData(page){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'fac?page=' + page,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $("#results").html(data);
            })
            .fail(function()
            {
                alert('No response from server');
            });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What does your blade file look like?

Comment: @btl blade partials?

Comment: No the page you are trying to render.

Comment: @btl https://imgur.com/a/yKeFm here's a screenshot

Comment: when i press back in browser, page only shows partial views code ive included, not whole page

Comment: Is that the entire blade file? No `@extend(...)`?

Comment: it extends from master, but i think it's not the issue master only yield contents and assets.. the issue is i can't render whole page when press back or forward between /fac and /univ uri, it shows only code from partial layouts

Comment: I see the `section('contents')` in the image, so as long as that same file has `@extend('master')` it should render the entire page. It sounds like something is missing in the blade and no `@extend()` is being called.

Comment: no, i think the problem is in controller. if request is ajax my controller execute my partial views and render it. but the case is, i go back from different page (not paginate links, if it's paginate links ofc it's trigger ajax requests). so my controller isnt rendering views